# SQL*PLUS How to place argument inside string

Tags: sqlplus

I am passing a string into sql script in &1 and unplugging pdb. I am required to enter path to file location where the xml from unplug will be placed, I would like the path to contain the string passed in &1, something like this d:\Oracle\oradata\gl_db&1&1.xml.

The path itself needs to be quoted in SQLPLUS script, like this "d:\Oracle\oradata\gl_db&1&1.xml" where &1 would be replaced with the variable passed from powershell as "$Variable".

I suspect this problem has a really simple solution but I can't seem to figure it out, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the answer myself, the issue was simply in the dot before xml extenstion, to have dot work correctly after &1(&1.), simply make it 2 dots, like this &1..